# Save and Scraping multiple pages with BeautifulSoup and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I tested my code with jupiter notebook with this code

```
...
rname = soup.find('p', 'con_tx')
#rnamelis = rname.findAll('p')
rname
from urllib.request import urljoin
  story=[]
  #review_text = lis[0].find('p').getText()
  #list_soup =soup.find_all('p', 'con_tx')
  story=rname.getText()
  story
```

and it worked well.

> (result) '전 여친에 ...'

But when I tried to scrape multiple pages

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.request import urljoin
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests


base_url = 'https://movie.naver.com/movie/bi/mi/basic.nhn?code='
pages =['177374','164102']
url = base_url + pages[0]
story = []
for n in pages:
    # Create url
    url = base_url + n

    # Parse data using BS
    print('Downloading page %s...' % url)
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()
    html = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    #print(soup.find('p', 'con_tx'))

    rname = soup.find('p', 'con_tx')
    story=rname.getText()
    data = {story}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.head()
    df.to_csv('./moviestory.csv', sep=',', encoding='EUC-KR')
```

An error message came out.

> ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

How do I fix my code?
[Crawling area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Evtt.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but one thing I'm noticing is you are overwriting your dataframe each time. Also don;t know why you initialise story as a list, and then store it as a dictionary in the loop.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests


base_url = 'https://movie.naver.com/movie/bi/mi/basic.nhn?code='
pages =['177374','164102']

df = pd.DataFrame()
for n in pages:
    # Create url
    url = base_url + n

    # Parse data using BS
    print('Downloading page %s...' % url)
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    rname = soup.find('p', 'con_tx')
    story=rname.getText()
    data = [story]
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(data), sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)

df.to_csv('./moviestory.csv', sep=',', encoding='EUC-KR')
```

Comment: My code had some misses. I knew it because of your answer and it works well. Thank you for your answer.